# Создать Boolean массив

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как создать boolean массив, в котором длина будет равна кол-ву элементов моего recycler'a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и более экономно:

```
BitSet boolArr = new BitSet(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, просто взять и создать:

```
boolean[] boolArr = new boolean[recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()];
```